# Unicode map from Font Awesome 4 to Font Awesome 5

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have several css files that contain hard-coded FA 4 Unicode values. Does there exist a map from FA 4 Unicode to FA 5 Unicode?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4#name-changes

Comment: Thanks. This map may be something that I will end up using, but unfortunately it does not have the old Unicode values. I know that there is another cheat sheet with the old Unicode values and their names, but then I would have to match the old Unicode values to their name, and then that old name to the new Unicode value :) I was hoping there would be a utility or map for just Unicode values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the map, I had to use three different tables:

- https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/
- https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet
- https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4

With the help of some MySQL queries, I created the following map that relates the font awesome 4 name and Unicode value to its respective font awesome 5 name and Unicode value *only* if the Unicode values differ:

```
"fa4name","fa5name","fa4code","fa5code"
"fa-address-book-o","address-book","f2ba","f2b9"
"fa-address-card-o","address-card","f2bc ","f2bb"
"fa-arrow-circle-o-down","arrow-alt-circle-down","f01a","f358"
"fa-arrow-circle-o-left","arrow-alt-circle-left","f190","f359"
"fa-arrow-circle-o-right","arrow-alt-circle-right","f18e ","f35a"
"fa-arrow-circle-o-up","arrow-alt-circle-up","f01b ","f35b"
"fa-arrows","arrows-alt","f047 ","f0b2"
"fa-arrows-alt","expand-arrows-alt","f0b2 ","f31e"
"fa-arrows-h","arrows-alt-h","f07e ","f337"
"fa-arrows-v","arrows-alt-v","f07d","f338"
"fa-bell-o","bell","f0a2","f0f3"
"fa-bell-slash-o","bell-slash","f1f7","f1f6"
"fa-bookmark-o","bookmark","f097","f02e"
"fa-building-o","building","f0f7 ","f1ad"
"fa-check-circle-o","check-circle","f05d ","f058"
"fa-check-square-o","check-square","f046 ","f14a"
"fa-circle-o","circle","f10c","f111"
"fa-circle-thin","circle","f1db ","f111"
"fa-clipboard","clipboard","f0ea ","f328"
"fa-cloud-download","cloud-download-alt","f0ed ","f381"
"fa-cloud-upload","cloud-upload-alt","f0ee ","f382"
"fa-comment-o","comment","f0e5","f075"
"fa-commenting","comment-dots","f27a","f4ad"
"fa-commenting-o","comment-dots","f27b ","f4ad"
"fa-comments-o","comments","f0e6 ","f086"
"fa-credit-card-alt","credit-card","f283 ","f09d"
"fa-cutlery","utensils","f0f5 ","f2e7"
"fa-diamond","gem","f219","f3a5"
"fa-envelope-o","envelope","f003","f0e0"
"fa-envelope-open-o","envelope-open","f2b7","f2b6"
"fa-exchange","exchange-alt","f0ec ","f362"
"fa-external-link","external-link-alt","f08e ","f35d"
"fa-external-link-square","external-link-square-alt","f14c ","f360"
"fa-folder-o","folder","f114 ","f07b"
"fa-folder-open-o","folder-open","f115 ","f07c"
"fa-heart-o","heart","f08a","f004"
"fa-hourglass-o","hourglass","f250","f254"
"fa-id-card-o","id-card","f2c3","f2c2"
"fa-level-down","level-down-alt","f149 ","f3be"
"fa-level-up","level-up-alt","f148","f3bf"
"fa-long-arrow-down","long-arrow-alt-down","f175 ","f309"
"fa-long-arrow-left","long-arrow-alt-left","f177 ","f30a"
"fa-long-arrow-right","long-arrow-alt-right","f178 ","f30b"
"fa-long-arrow-up","long-arrow-alt-up","f176","f30c"
"fa-map-marker","map-marker-alt","f041","f3c5"
"fa-map-o","map","f278","f279"
"fa-minus-square-o","minus-square","f147","f146"
"fa-mobile","mobile-alt","f10b ","f3cd"
"fa-money","money-bill-alt","f0d6 ","f3d1"
"fa-paper-plane-o","paper-plane","f1d9 ","f1d8"
"fa-pause-circle-o","pause-circle","f28c","f28b"
"fa-pencil","pencil-alt","f040 ","f303"
"fa-play-circle-o","play-circle","f01d","f144"
"fa-plus-square-o","plus-square","f196","f0fe"
"fa-question-circle-o","question-circle","f29c","f059"
"fa-share-square-o","share-square","f045","f14d"
"fa-shield","shield-alt","f132","f3ed"
"fa-sign-in","sign-in-alt","f090","f2f6"
"fa-sign-out","sign-out-alt","f08b ","f2f5"
"fa-spoon","utensil-spoon","f1b1","f2e5"
"fa-square-o","square","f096","f0c8"
"fa-star-half-o","star-half","f123 ","f089"
"fa-star-o","star","f006","f005"
"fa-sticky-note-o","sticky-note","f24a ","f249"
"fa-stop-circle-o","stop-circle","f28e","f28d"
"fa-tablet","tablet-alt","f10a ","f3fa"
"fa-tachometer","tachometer-alt","f0e4 ","f3fd"
"fa-thumbs-o-down","thumbs-down","f088 ","f165"
"fa-thumbs-o-up","thumbs-up","f087 ","f164"
"fa-ticket","ticket-alt","f145 ","f3ff"
"fa-times-circle-o","times-circle","f05c","f057"
"fa-trash","trash-alt","f1f8 ","f2ed"
"fa-trash-o","trash-alt","f014","f2ed"
"fa-user-circle-o","user-circle","f2be ","f2bd"
"fa-user-o","user","f2c0","f007"
"fa-window-close-o","window-close","f2d4","f410"
"fa-calendar","calendar","f073","f133"
"fa-reply","reply","f112 ","f3e5"
"fa-window-close","window-close","f2d3","f410"
```

The first row has the column description.

Note that the table, [upgrading-from-version-4](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4), only lists changes in the name; it was necessary to also join on the two different cheat-sheets listed above where the names are the same, but the Unicode values differ.